# Jquery alphanumerical (+ special characters) regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to cross-check text input against a jquery regex that includes the following values...

```
- A-Z
- a-z
- 0-9
- !
- #
- $
- £
(preferably all currency characters?)
- %
- &
- -
- _
```

How can this be done?

EDIT I have tried the following regex.

```
/^[\w,'-]+$/i
```

But it is only alphanumerical.

Comment: I don't see any of the extra characters you want to match in your character set. I do see characters you didn't say you wanted to match (though you probably do want to match them).

Comment: Hi crush, i made that distinction in the edit. This is why i have posted the question. I also don't really understand the regex that I've tried.

Comment: Just add all the characters you want to match after the `\w,'-`. You'll need to escape a few of them with \. I'd suggest researching basic regular expression syntax. This is an extremely basic question, and is likely why you aren't getting a lot of help.

Comment: @crush thank you, I'll try that. May delete this question too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include all your symbols. Since "£" is a non-standard character, I've used the unicode representation: `^[\w!#$%&\u00A3-]+$`